select points on large points cloud devdept
I'm using devdept eyeshot on winform for visualize some points cloud of some milions of points (typically 3-4 millions, at most about 10 millions points).
I want to select some points around the mouse and want to select them while moving the mouse.
I saw the code samples for points selection and i made what i want and for small points cloud it works well.
I'm doing that with mousemove event, but every time mousemove is called i need to check if every point inside the points cloud is inside my area and for millions of points it take a while and meantime the interface is freezed and not work as intended.
Is there any efficent way to do this?
